# Converting a number from a string to an int with decimals separated by comma or dot

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, numbers, locale

I have a string which contains a number. It can be one with decimals, followed by either a comma or a dot, depending on the user's locale.

The numbers are actually hundredths and I want to convert them to plain old ints. For example, I want strings `"14.5"` and `"14,5000"` to end up as int `1450`.

It's probably me, but I can't figure out how to correctly convert this number into an int with a corresponding value when the decimals are separated by a comma. I've tried this:

```cs
double valueDouble;
double.TryParse(SpecificTemperatureTextBox.Text, NumberStyles.Any,
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out valueDouble);

int valueInt = Convert.ToInt32(valueDouble * 100);
```

But this comes out wrong sometimes. Here are my results:

> ```
> TextBox value     Expected result     Converted result
> "14"              1400                1400 (good)
> "14.0"            1400                1400 (good)
> "14.5"            1450                1450 (good)
> "14,0"            1400                14000
> "14,5"            1450                14500
> ```

Am I not using the [`System.Globalization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) correctly when I'm converting? I don't want to replace `,` with `.` in the string, because that seems too dirty.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to know (and use) the users locale. Or write some detection logic. There is no solution with just 1 TryParse().

Comment: If it depends on the user's locale, you're not going to be able to test both of these work at the same time (as in your test).

Comment: @HenkHolterman I thought `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` in the arguments for `TryParse` would handle that for me

Comment: It does, so your solution (probably) works.  You can't test both at the same time though, you'll have to test with different regional settings.

Comment: If you can safely assume there'll me no other decimal separator than `.` and `,` then this might work, too - ugly solution though: `int valueInt = Convert.ToInt32(SpecificTemperatureTextBox.Text.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "").PadRight(5, '0'));`

Comment: As long as the data conforms to that setting. Your sample data needs 2 different locales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe safest bet would be to try parse input with both cultures, something like this:

```
private static int ConvertStringValue(string value)
{
  decimal valDouble;

  var comma = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
  comma.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
  comma.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

  var dot = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
  dot.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
  dot.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

  if (decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Currency, comma, out valDouble))
  {
    return Convert.ToInt32(valDouble * 100); 
  }
  else if (decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Currency, dot, out valDouble))
  {
    return Convert.ToInt32(valDouble * 100);
  }
  else
  {
    return Convert.ToInt32(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome, this is exactly the thing that worked. I ended up using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which is apparently dependent on the regional settings (developing for Windows Phone 8.1 with .NET 4.5)

Answer (score 1):

Using CurrentCulture will correctly parse numbers with either dot or comma depending on the value of CurrentCulture. But not both simultaneously as in no culture dot and comma are interchangeable.

So, you will have to replace either all commas for dots or vice versa. Then parse with the 'dot separator culture' or 'comma separator culture' setting.

Comment: And worry about 12,500.00 vs 12.500,00

Comment: Question did not mention the separator of thousands, just fractional part separator. But even with separator of thousands just remove all but last dot or comma.